# Google Maps APIv3 Multiple Markers/Multiple Info Windows

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am setting up a map of different airport locations. My Markers are at the correct locations.

I have been trying to add infowindows but every InfoWindow is showing the same content from the last marker in the array.

How do I fix this so each marker will have its own unique info?

```
 `setMarkers(map, airports);
 }

  function setMarkers(map, locations) {

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
var airport = locations[i];
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(airport[1], airport[2]);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
html: airport[3],
});

 var contentString = 
<?php
 $num_rows = (count($locations) - 1);

 for($i = 0; $i < count($locations); $i++){

  $query = "SELECT * FROM airports WHERE ident='$locations[$i]'";
  $result = mysql_query($query, $link)
or die('Error querying database.');

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

if ($i == $num_rows){

echo "'<div id=\"content\">'+";
 echo "'<div id=\"siteNotice\">'+";
  echo "'</div>'+";
echo "'<b>" . $row['ident'] . "</b></br>'+";
echo "'" . $row['latitude_deg'] . ", " . $row['longitude_deg'] . "' +";
echo "'</div>'+";
  echo "'</div>';";
}
 }
 }
 ?>



 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
 content: contentString
});

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
//infowindow.setContent(this.html);
infowindow.open(map,this);
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store the data that you need for each infowindow in some sort of array that is accessible by an index number.

The index number is accessed when the user clicks on the marker. The index number is then used to construct the infowindow content on the fly and open the infowindow.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(event, index) {
  return function(){
    infowindow.content = markerArray[index].label + "<br>" + markerArray[index].text;
    infowindow.open(map,this);
  }
})(marker,i));
```

Code from: http://srsz750b.appspot.com/api3/polylines-multiple.html